# Which fuse connection corresponds to which mount?

Tags: linux, fuse

In Linux `/sys/fs/fuse/connections` (or anywhere you mount `fusectl`) exposes a control interface for fuse metadata.  But how do you know which of your fuse mounts corresponds to which numbered subdirectory in there?

Alternatively, how can your userspace program that's implementing a specific fuse filesystem know which connection number it has?

Answer (score 1):

The directory is a "device number". For example:

```
$ ls /sys/fs/fuse/connections/
44/
$ stat -c %d /run/user/1000/gvfs
44
```

I guess:

```
$ < /proc/mounts cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs stat -c '%d %n' | sort | join -t' ' -11 -21 - <(find /sys/fs/fuse/connections -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | sort)
44 /run/user/1000/gvfs
49 /home/kamil/a
53 /home/kamil/b
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to work for on `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`.  I'll look into that direction, though.

Comment: `doesn't seem to work` how exactly it doesn't "seem"?